# Different M2_HOME for a different Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is there a way for me to have eclipse start and point to a different M2_HOME for a specific workspace? When I start eclipse, M2_HOME points to ~/.m2/repository, but I want to change that for this specific workspace which is a maven project with lots of child modules.

The project keeps its own M2 repo, and I don't want this to affect my other projects not in this workspace that would continue to use the default ~/.m2/repository repo.

I am able to build this project fine by setting some ENV variables, like MAVEN_OPTS, to point to this other M2 repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Window->Preferences, select Maven->User Settings. You can select the settings.xml and the Local Repository.

[image]

Comment: Where is Workspace > Preferences? I see Eclipse > Preferences. Also, this is not going to affect my setting for other workspaces?

Comment: Sorry, Window->Preferences, not Workspace. All of these settings are stored in the workspace. Other workspaces won't be affected. All of the project within that workspace will use the same settings though.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Some differences were, as I work on an osx, my menu was under Eclipse > Preferences. Also, the value for Local Repository comes from settings.xml.